# Why is the voltage measurement across this resistor 0V? (TinkerCad) What's wrong with the circuit?

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, digital-logic, diodes, zener

Please help me understand why the voltage measurement across the Zener diode and resistor is 0V. How should I go about getting a 4V reading there? If you notice other problems, or have some suggestions on improvements, please shoot, I'm eager to learn.

For example how bad could leaving out the transformer and diodes (not the Zener) be?

When I want to power the Arduino from the battery, I could just simply add a wire from the positive terminal to Vccin right?

I've made this circuit design in Tinkercad, but I'm very new to electronics, and it's my first design, so bear with me.

I need Arduino pin D8 to digital.read() a HIGH signal from this circuit, when the slide switch is ON.

I wanted to use a Zener diode to ensure the voltage never exceeds 4 volts even if I add a bigger power supply (or example, 18V.) I added a 2.7k resistor after the Zener to limit current. Same for the ground pin, although this seems overkill now.

To understand the rest of the circuit:

The resistor and switch on the top breadboard represent an outside audio device. The left breadboard with the capacitors and voltage divider is to isolate audio signal from the DC power and bias it with 2.5V for safe analog.reading() on pin A0.

I planned to add a 1:1 audio transformer too, but could not find this component in TinkerCAD.

I added the other two diodes (Schottky) on the top breadboard to block reverse (AC audio) current. Still learning about a better way. Blocking AC current doesn't seem so straightforward as blocking DC current. Is there a cheap and simple way with an inductor coil / low pass filter / optoisolator or so without bad side effects?

For clarity attached a picture of the circuit design on good old paper, too.

[TinkerCAD design](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/hAI3ylyjmMq-sizzling-fyyran/editel?sharecode=9t_9EJ1veLvNZ4_ZbyjcHCTSKnrJzjILiOyzEBuOp8U)

[image: TinkerCAD circuit]

[image]

[image: components]

Comment: 0V across a resistor means that there's no current through it. Does the Arduino function as you expect? Putting a 10K resistor in the ground connection is unusual, to say the least, I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This isn't the correct way to use a Zener diode to limit voltage; what you've done will actually *not* limit voltage, but simply subtract approximately 4 V from whatever voltage is applied (depending on input current, which is ideally zero). I also don't see where the Arduino is being powered; please draw the Arduino's power supply and ground on the schematic, as your question makes it sound like you don't have a ground connection.

Comment: Also, your question would be improved if you can add some paragraph breaks and format it so that people can understand what the question itself is first, and *then* read and understand the background information. Otherwise, I find myself reading through until I get to the question, then going back and reading again now that I understand why I'm being given all this information.

Comment: The Arduino is powered through usb right? I could add the vccin from the battery. But is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Gaai Your schematic doesn't indicate this, and I'm not sure how to make sense of the tinkercad diagram.

Comment: @Hearth substracting the voltage is what I want. The audio device I'm talking about needs as much as possible power from the 9v battery.

Comment: I undestand you mean the pencil circuit? There I added a dotted line from 9v to vccin? It's my first circuit design, so I don't really know what Im missing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you want to use the zener like this; if you applied 18 V you'd still see 14 V (=18 - 4) at the pin. You want the zener to limit the voltage, so it should be connected between the pin and ground, with a resistor between the input signal and the pin.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you meant with substract. I indeed want to limit the current to the arduino, but not to the rest of the circuit. Really?? Then I've completely misunderstood the zener diode I guess.

Comment: @Gaai The schematic doesn't show a usable connection to the negative terminal of the battery. You need to hook up both terminals for anything to work. I'm not sure if the Vccin that you're talking about is before or after the arduino's linear regulator, but if it's after, applying 9 V will break things.

Comment: @Gaai Are you trying to limit *current*, or *voltage*?

Comment: Ah right, the voltage. Caught me

Comment: Once the switch is closed, there is a connection to the negative terminal right?

Comment: @Finbarr yes ofcourse, but I hoped there would be voltage there. That's what I designed this for ;)

Comment: @Gaai When the switch is closed, you have a *very* high-impedance path to ground through 10.7 kΩ of resistance, two diodes, and an AC source of unknown (to us, anyway) characteristics. That's not a usable ground connection.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did remove the ground resistor already. But might be a problem still.

Comment: @Gaai All the other stuff in series with ground is also going to be a problem. Ground should just be connected to ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problems.

- I needed to measure across the pins of the Arduino.
  <s>- I misunderstood the working of a Zener diode, thinking it would limit the voltage,  but as Hearth pointed out, it substracts. Will revert back to the voltage divider I used to use, I guess.</s>
- Actually didn't use the Zener diode correctly, it should have been across the D8 pin and the ground. Like you see in the below picture.
- I shorted the Arduino ground to the positive terminal of 9V battery.
- My ground path from the Arduino to the negative terminal of the battery had too much impedance?? (I swapped the direction of current flow now (plus/min terminals), which from the Arduino's point of view, cleared the ground path). I'm not sure if this is cheating ;)
- The ground pin resistor was indeed overkill.
- Here's the improved circuit, on TinkerCad:
  [image: Working circuit]

New learnings to be made: I noticed that the resistor value matters quite a bit, if the voltage supply goes far above the Zener voltage, the voltage rises more and more above it's rated value. In tinkercad.

Comment: You can use a zener diode to limit voltage, you've just not connected it in the right way to do that. And I'm not a mr.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try and put it in between pin D8 and Gr pin like you suggested. Too bad weekend is almost over, I want to work further on this! Gonna be late ;) 
I'm sorry for the mr confusion. Might have been just presumptious or perhaps because I connected the profile picture of mr Tony with you... anyway... cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a "transformer present" detect circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbs0SY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You must insert a capacitor (C1) between the transformer and input A0 in your circuit to decouple the DC current through the winding.

You need an additional ADC input protectinon, not shown here.

Comment: Wow, I'll check this out. I did read about decoupling capacitors yesterday. Thought I might need one between ground and D8 pin too, in my schematic. And that I could probably lose the ground capacitor. Staring at your circuit, it's starting to make sense... But as a newcomer all these ground lines and input lines leading to the outside edge are confusing. I'll need to get a grip off that. And check your simulation software out too. Great that you put this amount of effort in. Awesome place this is for learning.

Comment: Could you explain the chosen 'layout' of R1 and R2 (why 10k? And not 700 and 330 ohm?) and Zener diode? I guess I expected a 700 ohm resistor before the switch and then the value of R1 to be 330/150 and then the Zener diode on the spot of R2.

Comment: @Gaai: We have 9V supply here and the Arduino reads 4.5 V as "active", the voltage divider R1/R2 delivers this. The low transformer DC resistance of some ohm is ignored here. The Z diode D1 is just a protection if V2 > 10 V or reverse connected or V1 has unexpected high AC voltage. I wanted a small DC current through the transformer because DC current in an audio transformer degrades the signal quality. This in mind 2 x 100k would be better, but such a high impedance makes the input sensitive to touching the wires with fingers. So 10 k is a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @Gaai: This circuit assumes that the Arduino VIn is directly connected to +Battery and always on. If you turn on the Arduino together with the audio signal, the circuit is meaningless (as your original circuit) because the input would always be on when the Arduino is active.

Comment: Ah, I guess I should've explained better that my audio device needs 6-9V to produce its audio. And the switch is inside of it. Operated by the outside. The easiest would be to get the Analog input to read the switch aswell. But I cannot use analog.read() unfortunately. Do to other software running.